# Margin auto doesn't apply to whole inside content

Tags: html, css

Here is a content inside: `<div class="traki"> </div>`
I add following css:

```
.traki {margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;}
}
```

And goal is to set inside content center. but it doesn't apply, demo: http://buhehe.de/kalender-2018/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do an "auto" margin to vertically center an element.

There is a workaround though, you could try this:

```css
.container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.helper {
    #position: absolute;
    #top: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.content {
    #position: relative;
    #top: -50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="helper">
        <div class="content">
            <p>stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```